# Moodle - SQL query to return course enrollment based on date

Tags: mysql, moodle

This is what I have so far but it only returns course name and total enrollments:

```
SELECT c.fullname, COUNT(ue.id) AS Enroled
FROM prefix_course AS c 
JOIN prefix_enrol AS en ON en.courseid = c.id
JOIN prefix_user_enrolments AS ue ON ue.enrolid = en.id
GROUP BY c.fullname
ORDER BY c.fullname
```

Comment: What version `moodle` do you use?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.1.

Comment: Can you be more specific what data do you need? Do you want only the count of the enrolled users but filtered by date?